# How do time tracking application for software development freelancer work?

Tags: freelance-websites, time-management, time-tracking

I would like to understand how these companies who claim keeping track of the time a freelancer works on a project do their job. So far, I have learned that some just offer a timer in their app next to a project on which the freelancer should click when he starts working on the related project.Are there companies that use a better approach?

**Edit**

What algorithm, system or tools do those applications base their tracking on if not a simple timer?